# dockerode pass args to run command _ Nodejs Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerode

I created some network with these command :

```
docker network create --driver bridge my-network
```

and I have some docker image that already created with an dockerfile.

In docker documentation they said you can connect your container with this command:

```
docker run --network=my-network -itd --name=mycontainer busybox
```

in my nodejs I need to pass these args to my run function:

```
let options = ['some option']
docker.run('mycontainer', [], process.stdout, { Env: options }).then(data => {
                console.log(data)
            }).catch(err => { console.log(err) })
```

so return to my main question : How to join a docker to docker network ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last parameter "{ Env: options }" is used for that.

it refers to Docker API : https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.24/#31-containers
Look at 'Create container' --> The last part of the request is 'NetworkingConfig'.
You still have to found the good syntax in your JS app

Something like :

```
let options = ['some option']
docker.run('mycontainer', [], process.stdout, {
Env: options,
NetworkingConfig: {
      "EndpointsConfig": {
          "isolated_nw" : {
              "IPAMConfig": {
                  "IPv4Address":"172.20.30.33",
                  "IPv6Address":"2001:db8:abcd::3033",
                  "LinkLocalIPs":["169.254.34.68", "fe80::3468"]
              },
              "Links":["container_1", "container_2"],
              "Aliases":["server_x", "server_y"]
          }
      }
  }}).[...]
```